# PHPとAjaxでいいねボタンを実装したい

Tags: php, ajax

PHP と Ajax を使って Facebook のいいねボタンのような投票システムを作ろうと思っています。

ファイルがいくつかあるので、分けて説明していきます。

```
//ボタン表示のphpファイル
<button class="letsVote" data-id='buttonID' data-numhtml="countNum1">
        <span class="countNum1"><?php echo getVoteCount('buttonID'); ?></span>
</button>
```

続いて、

```
<?php
//----------------------------------------------------------
// 投票数取得関数
//----------------------------------------------------------
function getVoteCount($id) {
//ファイル名
$filename = "log/".$id.".count";
$fp = @fopen($filename, "r");
if ($fp) {
$vote = fgets($fp, 9182);
} else {
$vote = 0;
}
return $vote;
}
?>
```

投票数を表示するphpファイルは、

```
<?php 
//vote.php

//////ajaxデータを受信1
$file_id = $_POST["file_id"]; //ファイル名
$count = $_POST["count"]; //投票数
$cookieName = "vote_" . $file_id; //クッキー名。
$cookieTime = time() + 10; //クッキーの有効期限（投票を制限する秒数）

///////クッキーが有効
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName])){
     echo "クッキー制御により投票不可です。";

}else{
///////クッキーが無効＝カウントアップ
     $count = $_POST["count"]; //投票数

     //カウント数を書き出すファイル名
     $fileName = "log/" . $file_id . ".count";

     $fp = @fopen($fileName , "w"); //書き込みモードで開く

     flock($fp , LOCK_EX); //排他的ロック(書く準備) 他のロックをすべてブロック
     fputs($fp , $count); //カウント数を書き込み
     flock($fp , LOCK_UN); //ロック開放
     fclose($fp);

     setcookie($cookieName , $count , $cookieTime); //10秒有効のクッキーをセット

     echo "Complete"; //clickCount.jsにはここの値を返す
}
?>
```

jQuery のファイルは、

```
$(function(){

     $('.letsVote').on('click' , function(){

          $this = $(this);
          var id = $this.data("id"); //識別用ID（重複NG）
          var numHtml = "." + $this.data("numhtml"); //カウント数を表示するHTML
          var nowCount = Number($(numHtml).html()); //現在のカウント数
          var newCount = nowCount + 1;

          $.ajax({
               type : "POST",
               url : "vote.php",
               data: {
                    "file_id" : id,
                    "count" : newCount
               }
          }).done(function(data , datatype){
                    //送信先のvote.phpから、Completeが返ってきたらカウント更新
                    if(data == "Complete"){
                         $(numHtml).html(newCount);
                    }else{
                         alert("押しすぎ(´・ω・｀)");
                    }
               }).fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      $("#XMLHttpRequest").html("XMLHttpRequest : " + XMLHttpRequest.status);
                      $("#textStatus").html("textStatus : " + textStatus);
                      $("#errorThrown").html("errorThrown : " + errorThrown.message);
                  });
　　　　});
});
```

といったところで実装しようとしています。

ただ、いざ表示しようとしてみると、ボタン表示の PHP ファイルの

```
<?php echo getVoteCount('buttonID'); ?>
```

という部分がエラーになり、

> call to undefined function getVoteCount()

と表示されます。

buttonID を変数 `$id` にしてみたりしたのですが、上手く動いておりません。

どのように記述すれば表示側と取得側の連携ができるでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーは `getVoteCount()` が定義されていないというものなので、引数の問題ではないでしょう。`getVoteCount()` の書かれたファイルがボタン表示をしているファイルと別なら、requireないしincludeで読み込む必要がありますが、これはされていますか？（質問に書かれたコードではどちらも書かれていないので）

Comment: ファイルを一緒にしてボタンを押せるようにはなったのですが、jQueryの動きが常にelse{alert("押しすぎ");}になってしまいます。
どうしたらdata=="complete"になりますか？

Comment: 期待した `"Complete"` の代わりに何が返ってきているのか、 `if(data == "Complete")` の直前に `alert(data)` とか `console.log(data)` と書いて確認してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: クッキー制御によって投票できないと表示されるのですが、ロードした時点でクッキーが機能してしまっているのでしょうか！？

Comment: あ、一度目のクリックは
<b>Warning</b>:  flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vote/vote.php</b> on line <b>23</b>
という文字列が表示されてしまいます。

Comment: `flock()` の一番目のパラメータ、つまり `$fp` が boolean 型になっているというエラーですね。それが出るということは [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.fopen.php) に失敗して false が返ってきているのでしょう。`fopen()` に失敗する可能性を考慮すべきですが、まずは `@` を外して `fopen()` の失敗理由を確認されては？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29496/discussion-between-daiki-kojima-and-unarist)しましょう。

Comment: 自分で記述してお恥ずかしいのですが、$filename = "file/".$id.".cnt";というのは、◯◯.cntというファイルを別に用意してそこに投票数を出力するような形なのでしょうか？